# Randomly generated responses? C++

Tags: c++

I'm making a text based game with C++. I want the user to be able to choose from 3 options, then another 3 options, etc, etc. How would I go about doing this. I'm looking to make a game where events are randomly generated and it can be done again and again. Sorry for being vague.

Comment: Use `srand` and `rand` functions.  Sorry about being vague.

Comment: I suggest using lookup tables for the options.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an loop (`while(endGame == false){...}`) in which you are asking the user to provide the option (with e.g. `std::cin >> option`)?

If you want to generate the random number (based on it's value you can decide if some random event should occur) use [the `rand()` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/):

```
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
...
/* initialize random seed: */
srand (time(NULL));

/* generate secret number between 1 and 10: */
int secretNumber = rand() % 10 + 1;

if(secretNumber > 7){
   ... //some special event
}
```

Anyway. I highly suggest you to **get some basic knowledge about c++ and programming in general** first. Check some step by step tutorial or a book. The first steps are usually the hardest one ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your responses to be in text form, which I assume you do, the randomness of them may be limited (to keep them coherent).

I would do it by setting up a finite list of responses, then generating a random # to pick which one to use.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <time.h>       



using namespace std;

string generateRandomResponse() {
    srand (time(NULL));
    const int MAXSIZE = 1000; int i = rand() % 2 + 1;
string randomResponse[MAXSIZE];
randomResponse[0] = "This can be one response\n";
randomResponse[1] = "So can this\n";
randomResponse[2] = "So on and so forth\n";

return randomResponse[i];
}

int main() {
int userResponse = 0;
cout << "Hey you! What is your favorite number? ('1', '2', '3')" << endl;
cin >> userResponse;
cout << generateRandomResponse();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Modern C++ solution.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

// List of choices we want to give the user.
std::vector< std::string > options = { 
        {"Option 1"}, 
        {"Option 2"}, 
        {"Option 3"}, 
        {"Option 4"}, 
        {"Option 5"} };

// Prepare random number generator /////////////////////////////////////////
// Seed with a real random value, if available
std::random_device r;
std::default_random_engine e1(r());
// A random value from 0 up to (and including) count of options - 1
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(0, options.size()-1);

int nextRandomChoice()
{
    return uniform_dist(e1);
}

int main()
{
    std::string input;

    do 
    {
        const auto firstSelection = nextRandomChoice();
        const auto secondSelection = nextRandomChoice();
        const auto thirdSelection = nextRandomChoice();

        std::cout << options[firstSelection] << '\n'
            << options[secondSelection] << '\n'
            << options[thirdSelection] << '\n';

        std::cout << "Press Q to quit or ENTER for next selection:";
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
    } while ( input != "Q" );

    return 0;
}
```